# How to initialize a timer in Java?

Tags: java, timer

I am creating a game program in Java that needs frame animations, and needs to repaint the frame every 40ms. I'm not quite sure how to make a Timer handle these repaints, however. I've tried something like this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(null);
```

But I think I need to set the update time in the intialiser, is that right? How do I go about doing this, and also getting the timer to run when the program starts? Or run at all for that matter? I know null can't be right. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) (*assuming that you're talking about Swing*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Timer t = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  //Do your Stuff here
                }
            });

            t.start();
```

where delay is the integer value which shows the delay for the timer in milliseconds
and stop the timer when you wish by

```
  t.stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Timer timer = new Timer(50, this);
timer.start();
```

"50" is how often the timer goes off, in milliseconds.
...this calls an actionListener

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    //do stuff here
}
```

....then stop the timer

```
timer.stop();
```

An example:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    public Timer time1;
        public MyPanel() {
        time1 = new Timer(40,this);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
     }
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            //do stuff here
            repaint();
    }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //your paint method
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct your timer with delay and your custom action listener.

```
class TimerAction implements ActionListener{

    boolean isItTimeForTic = true;

   @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      //this is the place to define logic which will be invoked after every DELAY ms
   }
}
```

Then you use it like that:

```
int delay = 1; //you set your delay here 
Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new TimerAction());
timer.start();
```

If you want your timer to repaint a frame you can modify your TimerAction to take reference to frame and then call it's method in actionPerformed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a game you must have implemented runnable.So i suggest you do something like.

```
//1
    private boolean running = true;
    private long fps = 0;
  //  private static final int MAX_CPS = 50;
   // private static final long MS_PER_FRAME = 1000 / MAX_CPS;
    private static final long MS_PER_FRAME = 40;//in your case it is 40//cps is 25

    public void run(){
        while(running){
            long cycleStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            gameUpdate();//for updating your game logic
            repaint();//for stuff like painting

            long timeSinceStart = (cycleStartTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
            if(timeSinceStart < MS_PER_FRAME){
                try{
                    fps = MS_PER_FRAME - timeSinceStart;
                    Thread.sleep(fps);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    System.err.println("InterruptedException in run "+e);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.err.println("Exception in run "+e);
                }
            }//closig if
        }//closing while
    }//closing run


//Like in your case you want to paynt after constant time you can do somehting like
//2

  //  private static final int MAX_CPS = 25;
    private static final long MS_PER_FRAME = 40
    public void run(){
        while(running){
            gameUpdate();//for updating your game logic
            repaint();//for stuff like painting
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(MS_PER_FRAME);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    System.err.println("InterruptedException in run "+e);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.err.println("Exception in run "+e);
                }
            }//closig if
        }//closing while
    }//closing run
```

I suggest using 1 as it gives smothness to game